# Blocking installation of android apps on a Particular Manufacturer's Device

Tags: android, google-play

Is there any way through which I can restrict Android devices of a particular manufacturer from installing apps from google Play store.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no such way,, As it would be very unreliable since many new manufacturing companies register frequently with Android OS.
i.e: More than 15 companies are operating locally in my country..
besides the giants like samsung, sony, HTC etc.

You can restrict device on certain hardware or software features like, cpu architecture.

For complete list of filters available check the [official guide](http://developer.android.com/google/play/filters.html).